# Quarkus how to set environment variables in application.properties

Tags: java, postgresql, environment-variables, application.properties, quarkus

recently I swapped from thorntail to quarkus and I'm facing some difficulties trying to find how to set environment variables in application.properties in thorntail I used something like this `${env.HOST: localhost}` that basically means put environment variable, if you don't find anything put localhost as default is that possible to quarkus application.properties? I haven't found any issue on GitHub or someone that have an answered this problem?

Answer (score 57, accepted):

In `application.properties` you can use:

```
somename=${HOST:localhost}
```

which will correctly expand the `HOST` environment variable and use `localhost` as the default value if `HOST` is not set.

See [this](https://quarkus.io/guides/config-reference#with-environment-variables) for more information.

Comment: It does work with the latest versions of Quarkus (I've tested for versions >= 1.1)

Comment: What about int default values can we just use -1 as in this example?
```
quarkus.mailer.from=${SYSTEM_EMAIL:-}
quarkus.mailer.port=${EMAIL_SERVER_PORT:-1}
```
To specify empty string using `-` and default-int is `-1`

Comment: I am not sure I understand your problem. Can you try and explain it a little more?

Comment: I mean I am using for defaut values  `-` for empty string and `-1` for int initial values.  Is this correct usages ? Cannot find any best practises about this in Quarkus docs.

Comment: You can alternatively make the Java field `Optional` and not have to pass a default value

Comment: Yes, but in my case I am using those values vor mailing integration and not injecting them as a fields. Probably will upgrade platform to 1.11.1.final soon, where we have warnings instead of server keystore error when using ${HOST} without default values

Comment: Where is this documented ?not at https://quarkus.io/guides/config

Comment: https://quarkus.io/guides/config-reference#property-expressions

Answer (score 10):

Alternatively, you do not need refere environment variable in application.properties, just refere variable in your code directly:

```
@ConfigProperty(name = "my.property", defaultValue = "default value")
String myProperty;
```

and specify it using env variable like this:

```
export MY_PROPERTY="env var" && java -jar myapp.jar
```

or using command line definition -D

```
java -Dmy.property="CL key" -jar myapp.jar
```

Please refere Quarkus configuration guide https://quarkus.io/guides/config